# Regex to match set of discrete non-repeating words

Tags: regex

How do I write a regex to match a set of discrete non-repeating words separated by commas.

The *non-repeating* part is not so important though. Importantly I want to match a set of discreted words separated by commas, and want it as short as possible. Also I'm not able to use multiple lines of pattern, It should be done with one pattern.

Edit: For example, I have a list of words `food, exercise, rest, walk`.
The pattern should then allow `food,rest` and `exercise, rest, walk` but should reject `food, rest, rest` and `walk, run` (first one contains repeating words, second one contains `run` which is not in my list.

Comment: Can you give examples?

Comment: Do you have to use a regex? If I understand the problem you are trying to solve, a relatively simple coded algorithm would be sufficient, and would probably be faster and easier to understand for the next guy maintaining the code.

Comment: @Dave I don't have an option to use code. It is all set by others. Only thing I could do is to add a single line regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This regex works in javascript.

To find just those 4 words, without repeating doubles :

```
(\b(?:food|walk|rest|exercise)\b)(?!.*\1)
```

For example:
Given the string "food, rest, rest, food, run" it would only find "rest" and  "food".

The \b are word boundaries.
That way it would for example get a match from "food," since it's in the list.  But not from "foody,".

The \1 is a back reference to capture group 1.
Because of the negative lookahead `(!`, if the same word is further in the string then it won't match.
So in the case of repeated words, it only matches the last one.

#### The anti-version of the regex:

To find words not in the list, without doubles:

```
(\b(?!food|walk|rest|exercise)\w+\b)(?!.*\1)
```

Comment: So can we make this regex to somehow match comma separated words `exercise, rest, walk` and reject duplicates?

Comment: Sure. It has been added.